# How to add OneSignal push notification icon to config.xml (Android)

Tags: ionic2, onesignal

I am implementing OneSignal push notifications with rest api so I want to set large icon and small icon to the notification but it is difficult to configure. What I did till now:

1. I have generated icons using Android Asset Studio.
2. I have created OneSignal folder inside resources folder.
3. In OneSignal folder I kept different size icons.

In `config.xml` file:

```
<platform name="android">
<resource-file src="resources/onesignal/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_icon.png" />
</platform>
```

Can you please guide me how to achieve this.

Is it possible to send an icon from my backend Node.js (Using OneSignal rest API).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have two separate problems:

**Problem 1: Add Android icons to `config.xml`**

Follow section 4 of [OneSignal icons documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/customize-notification-icons):

```
<resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
```

**Problem 2: Dynamic icons through REST API**

I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Thank you Frola i got it something like this `<icon density="xxxhdpi" src="platforms/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />`